# How to process audio from Youtube live stream video using Python?

Tags: python, pyaudio, pafy, yt-dlp

I have tried several methods to extract audio from live youtube stream video, but they didn't work. I have tried the following snippets.

```
import youtube_dl
import wave

def process_audio(chunk):
    # Process the audio data in the chunk
    pass

ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }],
    'on_progress_callback': process_audio,
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUKwTVAc0Vo'])
```

Kindly guide if there is some other method to do this task.

Comment: Hey @khizer, did you find a way of achieving this?